# How to experimentally determine the relation between magnetic moment and spin angular momentum of a quantum particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

In quantum mechanics the spin magnetic moment in terms of angular momentum is given by
$\mu=g\frac{e}{2m}L$, where $g≈2$

Now the question I was wondering, how do you determine this with experiments? I figured that you would have to measure $\mu$ and $L$ seperately and then notice that they are related by $g\frac{e}{2m}$. However, the problem is that I have not found any experiment that measures the spin of an quantum particle directly and was wondering how one might do that. The Stern-Gerlach experiment is not good since it only measures $\mu$.

Comment: How about Einstein-de-Haas effect ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment section, I think Einstein-de Haas effect is an experiment, that you were looking for. Since this is described well in literature, I will just give the wikipedia entry to start with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93de_Haas_effect

To point out the main idea: There is an iron cylinder inside a coil under current that creates magnetic field, such that the magnetisation is saturated, i.e. (almost) all spins are aligned. Then the polarity of magnetic field reversed.

Now on the one hand the magnetisation $M$ can be measured for both orientations of the magnetic field. We have

$\Delta M = 2N\mu_{sz}$

for the change of magnetisation, due to $N$ spins flipping, each having the magnetic spin moment in z-direction $\mu_{sz}$.

On the other hand the reslting change of angular momentum, must be compensated by the change of mechanic angular momentum of the cylinder, i.e. when the magnetic field is reversed, the cylinder starts to rotate.

$\Delta S = 2Ns_z = -L$

Since the cylinder is hung up on a thread that resists the rotation, there will be a maximum angle $\phi$ to which it rotates. I will omit the equations that lead up to:

$|\Delta S| = c \phi$

with a constant $c$ that is determined by the experimental setup (i.e. radius of cylinder, its mass and the spring constant of the thread).

Measuring these two physical quantities, we can calculate:

$\frac{\Delta M}{\Delta S}= \frac{\mu_{sz}}{s_z} = \gamma_s$

Most of this argumentation can be found in "Experimentalphysik 3" by Wolfgang Demtröder.